# Site settings to opt out from "Recent Tags" & "Recent Badges"

Tags: feature-request, preferences

There is a similar setting for hiding "Hot Network Questions". Is there any interest in doing the same for these two as well?

Rationale:

1. The recent tags are almost never relevant to me but most importantly it is a piece of UI that I hardly notice
2. I really don't see the value in having a list of badges that people have recently earned.

---

For clarification I'm talking about the sections highlighted in red

[image]